# django signin and signout function

Tags: python, django, session

im a newbee to django.. trying to make signin and signout fuctions.. but for some reason or other, its not working.. the code is proper according to me.. but after clicking login button.. it again loads the default ip address without any urlconf..

here is my code

-------views.py-------

```
    def signin(request):
    form=loginform(request.POST)
    try:
        username=request.POST.get("username")
        password=request.POST.get("password")
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if request.method== POST:
            if user:
                auth.login(request,user)
                M='loggedin as %s'%username
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/signedin/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid/')
    except:
        pass
        M=0
    response=render_to_response("users.html",{"form":form, "M":M},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return response

def signout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

-----forms.py--------

```
class loginform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=members
        fields=['username','password']
        widgets={
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

----------users.html----------

```
<html>
<title>users</title>    
    <head><h1>users</h1></head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
        {% if M %}
        YOU ARE {{M}}
        {% else %}
        you are not logged in
        {% endif %}
        <a href="signout">LOGOUT</a>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if u want make a sign the **URL**, has to look like these:

```
url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {
        'extra_context':
            {
            'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
    }, name='example'),
url(r'^logout$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
    {
        'next_page': '/',
    },
    name='logout'),
```

and the **html** you have to add `action:"/login"` and no just `action:"."`

Comment: yea.. that's there.. but without using login view also.. we can make ryt.. a basic one.. like my code.. ?

Comment: @Sidharth well i don't sure, because i am newbie too, but i try your code with my code and it Works, ofcourse, i am using the `auth.views.login` in Url.py